# Chiral symmetry of Dirac Equation

Tags: dirac-equation, chirality

When studying the argument in the subject, I need to show that $\exp^{-i\alpha\gamma^5}\gamma^0=\gamma^0\exp^{+i\alpha\gamma^5}$. How can I do this? Should I write the Taylor expansion of the exponential and directly apply anticommutation? Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Your way is pretty direct. You only have terms in the form $\gamma_0 (\gamma^5)^n$, which then alternate in sign with $n$ when you swap them around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another (equivalent) approach: for any matrix $A$,
$$
\gamma^0 \mathrm e^{A}\gamma^0=\mathrm e^{\gamma^0 A\gamma^0}
$$
as can be seen using $\mathrm e^{B^{-1}AB}=B^{-1}\mathrm e^A B$.

The property $\mathrm e^{B^{-1}AB}=B^{-1}\mathrm e^A B$ is one of the basic properties of the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Properties). There are multiple proofs of this property. For example, [here](http://faculty.uml.edu/dklain/exponential.pdf) there is a proof using the series expansion of the exponential. Maybe a more straightforward proof is
$$
\mathrm e^{B^{-1}AB}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{B^{-1}AB}{n}\right)^n=
\lim_{n\to\infty}B^{-1}\left(1+\frac{A}{n}\right)^nB=B^{-1}\mathrm e^AB
$$

Comment: and how do you demonstrate your general identity? thank you!

Comment: @ArnaldoMaccarone see the edit.