# Covariance of the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, dirac-equation, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-matrices

In the Ashok Das book "Lectures on quantum field theory" , it's written that in page 76 : therefore, the matrix $ S~ \gamma^0~ S^\dagger ~ \gamma^0$ must be
proportional to the identity matrix (this can be easily checked by
taking a linear combination of the sixteen basis matrices in (2.100)
and calculating the commutator with $\gamma^\mu$ ). As a result, we can denote

$$ S~ \gamma^0~ S^\dagger ~ \gamma^0 = b~ 1 $$

Do any one know how this can be made?

**Edit**

Where Dirac equation

$$iγ^ μ ∂ μ − m ψ(x) = 0 .$$

Under a Lorentz transformation
$$x^ μ → x ^{′ μ} = Λ^μ_ν x^ ν ,$$

the transformed equation has the form

$$iγ^ μ ∂_μ′ − m ψ ′ (x ′ ) = 0,$$

where

$$\psi'(x') = \psi'(\Lambda x)= S(\Lambda) \psi(x) $$

and

$$\psi(x) = S^{-1}(\Lambda) \psi'(x') .$$

Comment: where the Dirac spinor $\psi' = S \psi $, please look Equ. (3.42) in the book ..

Comment: I thought it's a famous book like Peskin, so it's here on this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3h25xfaee14nab/Lectures%20on%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The covariance of Dirac equation is a whole section , so it's better to seen in the book, also Equ. (2.100) and (3.42) consist of many equations .. any way i think studying Dirac equation is  common in different references, the transformation matrices and so ..

Comment: No problem , i will add my question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need two lemmas:

$$B\mathrm e^A B^{-1}=\mathrm e^{BAB^{-1}}\tag{1}$$
(see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296921/chiral-symmetry-of-dirac-equation/296930#296930) for the proof).

And the fact that the gamma matrices satisfy $$(\gamma^{\mu})^\dagger=\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0\tag{2}$$
(the proof is easy; one just considers the cases $\mu=0$ and $\mu=i$ separately).

---

Here, $S$ is defined as
$$
S=\exp\left[-\frac i2 \omega_{\mu\nu}\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]}\right]
$$
where $\gamma^\mu$ are the Dirac gamma matrices.

Using $(1)$ together with $(\gamma^0)^2=1$, we can see that
$$
\gamma^0 S\gamma^0\overset{(1)}=\exp\left[-\frac i2 \omega_{\mu\nu}\gamma^0\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]}\gamma^0\right] \tag{A}
$$

Now, we use $(2)$ together with $(\gamma^0)^2=1$ to conclude that
$$
\gamma^0\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]}\gamma^0=\gamma^0\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^{\nu]}\gamma^0\overset{(2)}=-(\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]})^\dagger\tag{B}
$$

Finally, using $(\mathrm A)$ and $(\mathrm B)$, we see that
$$
\gamma^0 S\gamma^0=\exp\left[+\frac i2 \omega_{\mu\nu}(\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]})^\dagger\right]=S^\dagger
$$
as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Thanks. You mean here with the brackets $\gamma^{[\mu} \gamma^{\nu]}$ that they are anti commuting matrices ?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, $\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]}\equiv\frac12 [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]$.